# Extract csv files from path to multiple files in bash

Tags: bash, shell, files, sed, grep

I have a files multiple file path for backup purpose ,now i want to filter it based on ".csv " fromat. I have tried this.

```
filesall=(/home/abc/allfiles/*)
files=$((${filesall[@]}|grep -F ".csv"))
files=$(${filesall[@]}|grep -oe "*.csv")
```

but unable to extract .csv files from **$filesall** . I know i can achieve it like this

```
files=(/home/abc/allfiles/*.csv)
```

any suggestion ,how can i get all .csv files from filesall.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is really not the best way to do this. Why parse the array? A simpler approach would be something like:

```sh
path=/home/abc/allfiles
filesall=(${path}/*)
files=(${path}/*.csv)
```

If you insist on doing it your way, you would have to do something like:

```sh
files=($(for file in "${filesall[@]}"; do [[ $file =~ \.csv$ ]] && echo $file; done))
```

or

```sh
files=($(printf "%s\n" "${filesall[@]}" | grep '\.csv$'))
```

But both of the above break if any of your file names contain whitespace.
(They can be made to work with spaces if you precede them with `saveIFS="$IFS"; IFS=$'\n'`
and follow them with `IFS="$saveIFS"`, but they still break on newline.)

Comment: If we changed your last command to `$(printf "%s\0" "${filesall[@]}" | grep -z '\.csv$')` (to handle file names that contain whitespace), how could we get the result into array correctly? Would setting IFS to \0 do that?

Comment: @G-Man no idea. I thought I could get it to work but couldn't manage it. Probably because the Right Way© is to use a glob instead.

Comment: @terdon Thanks for your reply ,how can i read files as array ? files contain all the concatenated csv files.

Comment: @Aashu what do you mean? All these methods read the files into an array. Do you want to read the _contents_ of the files?

Comment: @terdon Sorry, i was ssaying regarding files=($(printf "%s\n" "${filesall[@]}" | grep '\.csv$')) this expression.

Comment: @Aashu that expression is just completely wrong. Why do you insist on it? Just use the glob, that's what it's for.

Answer (score 0):

Building on terdon’s answer, here’s one that seems to work:

```
filesall=(all files)
files=(); for file in "${filesall[@]}"; do [[ $file =~ \.csv$ ]] && files+=("$file"); done
```