# How can I write a script which updates a text file?

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing

I have made this script:

```
#PACKAGES.TXT
array2=(
`find . -type f -iname *t?z|awk '{print $1}'|cut -d / -f 3`
)
funzioneZ() {
echo -e " PACKAGE NAME: $i "  
}
array3=(
`find . -type f -iname *t?z|awk '{print $1}'|cut -d / -f 1,2`
)
funzioneA() {
echo -e " PACKAGE LOCATION: $i "  
}
array4=(
`for i in */*txz;do xz -l $i |tail -n 1|cut -d . -f 1|awk '{print $3, "K"}'; done`
)
funzioneB() {
    echo -e " PACKAGE SIZE (compressed): $i "  
}
rm MANIFEST2
for i in ${array2[@]};do funzioneZ $i >> MANIFEST2;done
for i in ${array3[@]};do funzioneA $i >> MANIFEST2;done
for i in ${array4[@]};do funzioneB $i >> MANIFEST2;done
```

The actual result:

```
 PACKAGE NAME: pam-1.1.8-x86_64-2mg.txz 
 PACKAGE NAME: tvtime-1.0.2-x86_64-3_SBo.txz 
 PACKAGE LOCATION: ./a 
 PACKAGE LOCATION: ./x 
 PACKAGE SIZE (compressed): 453 
 PACKAGE SIZE (compressed): 606
```

But I want the result to look like this:

```
 PACKAGE NAME: pam-1.1.8-x86_64-2mg.txz 
 PACKAGE LOCATION: ./a
 PACKAGE SIZE (compressed): 453 
 PACKAGE NAME: tvtime-1.0.2-x86_64-3_SBo.txz 
 PACKAGE LOCATION: ./x 
 PACKAGE SIZE (compressed): 606
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. In order to help we need to see your input file. Please [edit] your question and give us an example of the input. Also, is the only problem the order that the lines are printed in or is there another issue?

Comment: These will not _directly_ answer your question, but I see several problems: (1) You should ***always*** quote deferred wildcards; e.g., `find . -type f -iname "*t?z"`. (2) Perhaps most important: you seem to assume that `find . -type f -iname "*t?z"` and `*/*txz` will produce the same list of files, in the same order. This assumption is invalid. (3) You should quote shell variables references unless you have a good reason not to, and you’re sure you know what you’re doing; so it should be `for i in "${array2[@]}";do funzioneZ "$i"`. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … (4) ``a=(`find …`)`` is an unreliable way to construct an array — see [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155197/80216). (5) For what you’re doing, you probably don’t really want to use the **`-e`** option of `echo`. (6) It hurts my head to think about `2`, `3`, and `4` corresponding to `Z`, `A`, and `B`, respectively. Not to mention the fact that `array2` is `-f 3` and `array3` is `-f 1,2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution: clean and easy

```
for i in ${array1[@]};do echo -e "PACKAGE NAME:$i " >> MANIFEST2 && echo -e "PACKAGE SIZE: `xz -l $i |tail -n 1|cut -d . -f 1|awk '{print $3, "K"}'`" >> PACKAGES.TXT




PACKAGE NAME:a/pam-1.1.8-x86_64-2mg.txz 
PACKAGE SIZE: 453 K
PACKAGE NAME:x/tvtime-1.0.2-x86_64-3_SBo.txz 
PACKAGE SIZE: 606 K
```

Comment: Well, this is clearly an answer to a different question. The above question asks about `array2`, `array3`, and `array4`, with data being written to one file. This answer talks about `array1` (which might be the same as `array2`, but how are we to know?) driving two streams of data being written to two files — and then _shows_ the two streams magically interleaved.